Geocoding API components ignores street_number and subpremise
I'm trying to request Geocoding API with components parameter but it ignores street_number and subpremise.
Here is my request URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:LT|locality:vilnius|route:boksto|street_number:1|subpremise:1

Both street_number and subpremise are double checked and must be valid, but the response looks like this:
{
   "results" : 
   [
      {
         "address_components" : 
         [
            {
               "long_name" : "Bokšto gatvė",
               "short_name" : "Bokšto g.",
               "types" : 
               [
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Vilnius",
               "short_name" : "Vilnius",
               "types" : 
               [
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Vilniaus miesto savivaldybė",
               "short_name" : "Vilniaus m. sav.",
               "types" : 
               [
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Vilniaus apskritis",
               "short_name" : "Vilniaus apskr.",
               "types" : 
               [
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Lithuania",
               "short_name" : "LT",
               "types" : 
               [
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Bokšto g., Vilnius, Vilniaus m. sav., Lithuania",
         "geometry" : 
         {
            "bounds" : 
            {
               "northeast" : 
               {
                  "lat" : 54.6811699,
                  "lng" : 25.2932528
               },
               "southwest" : 
               {
                  "lat" : 54.6762551,
                  "lng" : 25.2893177
               }
            },
            "location" : 
            {
               "lat" : 54.6786798,
               "lng" : 25.2912834
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : 
            {
               "northeast" : 
               {
                  "lat" : 54.6811699,
                  "lng" : 25.2932528
               },
               "southwest" : 
               {
                  "lat" : 54.6762551,
                  "lng" : 25.2893177
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ_aYCJT6U3UYRbNzqWrcdYyM",
         "types" : 
         [
            "route"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?
